# Publishing page, missing images

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, cme, image

I have a Page Template with several Component Templates. In the Template Builder everything shows and seems fine.

When I publish my page and load it in my browser, everything shows except the images. I've inspected the html:

```
<img align="left" alt="" src="/Images/00418724_thumb.jpg"></img>
```

This is the correct name of the image, but the folder called "Images" is empty on the site. I've tried putting the image by myself into the directory and it worked.

My question is what should I do in order to get and publish the images that I already have uploaded on the CME?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you need to set the publish location for binary files in your cd_storage_conf.xml used by the deployer to something like the below:

On the server where your Deployer service is running, open the cd_storage_conf.xml file and set the Storage element's Root Path attribute

```
  <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
     <Root Path="c:\inetpub\wwwroot\yourwebsite" />
  </Storage>
```

Then within your `<ItemTypes>` section you will need something like this:

```
<Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="defaultFile" cached="false" />
```

Note this assumes that all binaries should go to the filesystem.

Once you've done that, you should restart the Deployer windows service and republish any pages in order for the images to be published to the newly configured directory.

Comment: Thank you, Rob, for the fast reply. Unfortunately, no result yet. :(

Comment: Also, if you are currently using a different directory than "Images" -- you may just need to change the properties on the Publication to match reality. "Images" is just a default value, you are free to change them.

Comment: I didn't mention that you may need to restart the deployer service and republish your page in order for the changes to be reflected. updated my answer.

Comment: I already did the restart and republishing, but nothing changed. And there are no images in the whole site directory. The directory is created but there is nothing inside.

Comment: Okey, the images are showing now! I restarted the machine just to be sure that everything will be restarted. It works now, thanks Rob!

Comment: Great that it works after Machine restart, but in case it is a production server or if it is not possible to restart machine, then instead of restarting the machine, just restart the App Pool in IIS of your Deployer (Which hosts the HTTPUpload.aspx) or may be you can re-start the Application Server at max in case there is any change in Storage or Deployer config.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I actually think that I restarted the deployer, the site and the services, but I might have missed something...